# Confusion with the derivation of the condition for minima in the diffraction with single slit

Tags: quantum-mechanics, diffraction

The usual argument for this is that we divide the slit into two halves, and when we pick a point on the upper half, “there is a point half the width of the slit below the point chosen which generates a wave cancelling out the wave emerging from the point chosen”.

Why must the quote part be true?

Answer (score 1):

Because of the phasor approach.

You can divide the single slit into $N (\rightarrow \infty)$ sources, each generating an electric field, which is a vector. You can represent it as a phasor on an Argand diagram and you can stack of the electric fields from your $N$ sources to get the total field on the screen. 
 In order to get zero intensity, you needs all the small phasor to cancel out (vectorially). 
 And, by geometry, if you pick one phasor, you will find the one pointing the opposite direction $1/2$ of the slit below, because the slit is symmetric about its centre point.

See [here](http://www.animations.physics.unsw.edu.au/jw/light/single-slit-diffraction.html#2) and [here](http://www.animations.physics.unsw.edu.au/jw/light/single-slit-diffraction.html#6) for a demo.

Answer (score 0):

It only works when the wavelength is short enough compared with the width of the slit.

Divide the slit into two halves, and pair each point in the top half with the point half the width below it.

For any point P some distance away, the path difference is defined as the difference between the distances to the two points in a pair. In other words, if T is a point in the top half of the slit and B is the point half the slit below it, the two paths are the lengths PT and PB, and the path difference is the difference between them. It is approximately the same for all pairs of T and B, if the distance to P is large enough that all lines PT and PB are approximately parallel.

If the path difference is half the wavelength, a wave maximum from the top half of the slit will arrive with a wave minimum from the bottom half and they will cancel.
If the slit width is less than the wavelength, the path difference will always be less than half a wavelength, so there will be no complete cancellation.

Comment: Can you justify on the point that "For any point some distance away, the path difference is the difference between the distances to the two points in a pair"?

Comment: I have clarified the paragraph on Path difference.